# In the Ardor platform, what are all the different "types" and "subtypes" in a transaction?

Tags: ardor, ignis

In the Ardor platform, there are different types of transactions. What do each number type represent? Some are asset transfers, send transaction, and voting. Where can I find a list of these types of transactions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the getConstants API and check the "transactionSubTypes" JSON array for a mapping of transaction types and sub types to their display name.

```
"transactionSubTypes": {
    "AssetIssuance": {
        "isPhasable": true,
        "subtype": 0,
        "mustHaveRecipient": false,
        "name": "AssetIssuance",
        "canHaveRecipient": false,
        "isGlobal": true,
        "type": 2,
        "isPhasingSafe": true
```

Comment: here is also a list to look up: https://github.com/mrv777/Ardor/blob/master/html/www/js/nrs.transactions.types.js

Answer (score 0):

This is the switch case I used to figure out what each $type is for:

```
    switch($type) {
      case "-4":
        $type = "Coin Exchange";
        break;
      case "-3":
        $type = "Account Control";
        break;
      case "-2":
        $type = "Payment";
        break;
      case "-1":
        $type = "Child Chain Block";
        break;
      case "0":
        $type = "Payment";
        break;
      case "1":
        $type = "Messaging";
        break;
      case "2":
        $type = "Asset Exchange";
        break;
      case "3":
        $type = "Marketplace";
        break;
      case "4":
        $type = "Account Control";
        break;
      case "5":
        $type = "Monetary System";
        break;
      case "6":
        $type = "Data Cloud";
        break;
      case "7":
        $type = "Suffling";
        break;
      case "8":
        $type = "Aliases";
        break;
      case "9":
        $type = "Voting";
        break;
      case "10":
        $type = "Account Properties";
        break;
      case "11":
        $type = "Coin Exchange";
        break;
      default  :
        $type = "Unknown Type";
     }
```

[image]

Comment: This is correct for now but we will probably add new transaction types and subtypes in the future so a better design would be to iterate over the types returned by getConstants and create a hash table or several hash tables depending on your design. You can see how this is implemented in the wallet in nrs.transaction.types.js NRS.loadTransactionTypeConstants() function